# pop-up a window from itextsharp annotation to display images and text

Tags: c#, javascript, itext

I want to add and pop-up window in C# project to display an image and text by clicking on itextsharp annotation.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation annot = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(stamper.Writer, c.rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, PdfAction.JavaScript("app.alert('action!')", stamper.Writer));
```

above code is used to display the alert and i want to customize it to my needs can someone please give me an option.i'm not familiar with javascript. or can i use any other options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a couple of annotations to achieve what you want.

Let me start with a simple text annotation:

Suppose that:

- `writer` is your `PdfWriter` instance,
- `rect1` and `rect2` are rectangles that define coordinates,
- `title` and `contents` are `string` objects with the content you want to show in the text annotation,

Then you need this code snippet to add the popup annotations:

```
// Create the text annotation
PdfAnnotation text = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(writer, rect1, title, contents, false, "Comment");
text.Name = "text";
text.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_NOVIEW;
// Create the popup annotation
PdfAnnotation popup = PdfAnnotation.CreatePopup(writer, rect2, null, false);
// Add the text annotation to the popup
popup.Put(PdfName.PARENT, text.IndirectReference);
// Declare the popup annotation as popup for the text
text.Put(PdfName.POPUP, popup.IndirectReference);
// Add both annotations
writer.AddAnnotation(text);
writer.AddAnnotation(popup);
// Create a button field
PushbuttonField field = new PushbuttonField(wWriter, rect1, "button");
PdfAnnotation widget = field.Field;
// Show the popup onMouseEnter
PdfAction enter = PdfAction.JavaScript(JS1, writer);
widget.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.E, enter);
// Hide the popup onMouseExit
PdfAction exit = PdfAction.JavaScript(JS2, writer);
widget.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.X, exit);
// Add the button annotation
writer.AddAnnotation(widget);
```

Two constants aren't explained yet:

JS1:

```
"var t = this.getAnnot(this.pageNum, 'text'); t.popupOpen = true; var w = this.getField('button'); w.setFocus();"
```

JS2:

```
"var t = this.getAnnot(this.pageNum, 'text'); t.popupOpen = false;"
```

This is, of course, explained in my book, more specifically in chapter 7. You can find a full example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=152). If you need a C# example, please look for the corresponding example [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C07).

If you also want an image, please take a look at this example: [advertisement.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/advertisement.pdf)

Here you have an advertisement that closes when you click "close this advertisement". This is also done using JavaScript. You need to combine the previous snippet with the code of the [Advertisement](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=143) example.

The key JavaScript methods you'll need are: `getField()` and `getAnnot()`. You'll have to change the properties to show or hide the content.

Comment: i want to add it to a desktop pdf reader application.i think you are refering to a web app..is there a way to popup customized windows form from a annotation.

Comment: Desktop / server, it doesn't matter. Actually,  if you check the original example in my book, you'll see that it's a standalone desktop application (so I don't get why you claim I'm talking about a web app). As for customizing the popup: you can do so within the limitations of what is specified in ISO-32000-1 and what is supported in the PDF viewer.

Comment: forgive my ignorance sir. found out it was possible.thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using an attachment instead of a popup. Below code will place an image in your pdf, and on click of image, it will open image with full resolution.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("source.pdf"));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("target.pdf"));

PdfAnnotation imgAttach = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), "", null, "PATH/TO/image.jpeg", "image.jpeg");

PdfAppearance app = stamper.getOverContent(1).createAppearance(100, 100);
Image img = Image.getInstance("PATH/TO/image.jpeg");
img.scaleAbsolute(100, 100);
img.setAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
app.addImage(img);

imgAttach.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, app);

stamper.addAnnotation(imgAttach, 1);
stamper.getOverContent(1).addImage(img);
stamper.close();
```