# How to get a popup window with an image for an annotation in a pdf using C# and itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to get a pop-up window when I click on a text annotation in a pdf document like 'Figure.1'.That pop-up window should display the image related to that mentioned figure.

[image]

As I mention in the image,

No 1: shows the annotation for 'Figure 1' .'Figure 1' can be inside a paragraph or like this way.

No 2 : shows the pop up window that i want to see when I click on the annotation shown in No 1. This popup window should display the image of 'Figure 1'

I have used this code to annotate the 'Figure 1'..:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation annotNote = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamper.Writer, m.rect,m.figureType,m.figureType);

stamper.AddAnnotation(annotNote, m.currentPage);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not believe that there is any way to "popup" a window with an image in it. If there were, I'm pretty sure we'd be seeing banner ads like crazy in PDFs.

Comment: As an example suppose that the 'Figure 1' is in the page number 10, in a paragraph of the pdf document as a text.But the relevant figure is in the page number 5.
So user wants to see what is the 'Figure 1' which is mentioned in the paragraph.So he has to go to the page number 5.
But without going through the pdf document user likes to see the 'Figure 1' in just one click. Therefore it is better if there is a feature,to user to see the 'Figure 1' in a new window when he clicks on the figure name in the paragraph.

Comment: And when the paragraph describes the 'Figure 1' it is hard to user to go again and again to the page number 5 and see that figure and understand the figure according to the description in the paragraph in page number 10.Therefore a popup window with an image of the relevant figure would be a comfortable feature for a pdf reader.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : dear sir can u help me for this kind of a feature to implement inside a pdf reader application..

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968916/pop-up-a-window-from-itextsharp-annotation-to-display-images-and-text