# iTextSharp - display text on hover

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate a PDF that contains words the reader may not know.  So I want to underline these words and then add a feature where (1) when the user hovers the mouse over the word, a definition pops up, and (2) if the user clicks on the popped-up definition, it goes to the Definitions section of the document.

I see example code to do this online, but it always requires that you know where the link will appear on the page, and in my case I'm generating a structured document (Chapters and Sections) so I do not know the position of the word.

I suspect it uses PdfAnnotation and Link but can't figure out exactly how.

Bonus points if the solution also works when the text is in a table cell (some of the solutions I see have problems there).

p.s. Some progress:

When I create my Definitions section, I call

```
this.Chunks[0].SetLocalDestination("Definitions");
```

When I add the challenging word to my PDF document, I call SetGenericTag() on the Chunk.  Then, in my override for PdfPageEvent.OnGenericTag() I do this:

```
PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(writer, rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, PdfAction.GotoLocalPage("Definitions", false));
writer.AddAnnotation(link);
```

which satisfies part of what I need - if I click on the word it takes me to the Definitions section of the document.  But there is still no definition that appears when you hover over the word.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a duplicate of [pop-up a window from itextsharp annotation to display images and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968916/pop-up-a-window-from-itextsharp-annotation-to-display-images-and-text)? This is also available in the official documentation: [How to add an onMouseOver javaScript action to a TextField?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-onmouseover-javascript-action-textfield) and [How to create a pop-up a window to display images and text?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-pop-window-display-images-and-text)

Comment: The stackoverflow link is the same as the second link from the official documentation; when I implement that code, in Windows Adobe reader when I mouse over my word I get the standard "add your reply to this comment" popup but it changes shape as I move the mouse around.  In the Mac it's the same popup but it flickers in & out of existence as I move the mouse around.  In neither case is there the option to click on it to jump to the Definitions section.

Comment: When I implement the code from the first link from the official documentation, it doesn't do anything when I hover over the word, and I get both the word and the text field in the same location on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, rect, "DefineButton-" + (++NumButtons));
PdfFormField field = button.Field;
field.Action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage("Definitions", false);
field.UserName = definition;
writer.AddAnnotation(field);
```

Comment: Of course, the Mac Preview app doesn't show the tooltip.  Sigh.