# iText(Sharp) - PushbuttonField inside Template inside Table Cell

Tags: pdf, itext

I am drawing an equation in a iTextSharp-generated PDF file.  Nothing complicated, stuff like:

```
x-y
--- + 3
 z
```

But with two interesting caveats:

1. The equation is drawn, along with some text, in a table cell
2. The table is drawn in a structured document (Chapters and Sections) so I don't know ahead of time where the cell is going to be drawn.

I'm solving this by drawing the equation in a template:

```
section.Add(new Paragraph("Here comes my equation in a table"));

PdfPTable outerTable = new PdfPTable(2);
outerTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Look at the next cell"))));

PdfTemplate template = pdfWriter.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
draw_my_equation_into(template);
Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(template);

PdfPTable innerTable = new PdfPTable(1);   // Inner table, inside cell (1, 0) in my outer table.
innerTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Here is my equation:"))));
innerTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(image));

outerTable.AddCell(innerTable);

section.Add(outerTable);
chapter.Add(section);
```

That works fine.  Good stuff.

But now I realize I would like to give the reader of my document some help understanding the equation if they want it, so I want to have some text appear if they hover the mouse over the equation, and let them jump to even more explanation if they click on the equation.  The only way I know to do that involves a PushbuttonField and generic tag on the chunk [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418631/itextsharp-display-text-on-hover).

But I cannot figure out how to add a PushbuttonField in this case, I don't have a Chunk to call SetGenericTag() on, and I don't know the location of the equation on the page.

Is creating a PdfTemplate the wrong way to go here?  Do I need to create my equation using some other method, so I can get a Chunk and call SetGenericTag()?  Or is there some way to find out the location of the equation so I can create my PushbuttonField?

===== Added later

I just realized that I can move the drawing of the template later, I can do the drawing during an OnCloseDocument() handler, I assume at that point it's done all the layout so it knows exactly where the template is being drawn.  But I don't know how to ask the template where it's being drawn ...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a rather convoluted, but functional solution, based on adding a CellEvent to the cell containing the equation.  It assumes that the cell containing the equation contains *only* the equation.  That's not a bad assumption, though I would like a more general solution.

```
    class EquationDrawer : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        IEquation m_equate;
        PdfTemplate m_template;

        public EquationDrawer(IEquation equate, PdfTemplate template)
        {
            m_equate = equate;
            m_template = template;
        }
        void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {
            // Draw the equation into the template
            m_equate.Draw(m_template);

            // Calculate the actual position on the page of where
            // the equation will be drawn by taking the cell rectangle
            // and insetting by the cell padding
            Rectangle bounds = m_equate.Bounds;
            Rectangle draw = new Rectangle(position.Left + cell.PaddingLeft,
                position.Bottom + cell.PaddingBottom,
                position.Left + cell.PaddingLeft + bounds.Width,
                position.Top - cell.PaddingTop);

            // Calculate where, in the overall equation, is the text
            // that I want to add a button to
            Rectangle text = m_equate.WhereIsMyText(draw);

            CreatePushbutton(m_template.PdfWriter, text, m_tooltip, m_dest);
        }

        void CreatePushbutton(PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rect, string tooltip, string localDestination)
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
            cb.SaveState();
            cb.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
            cb.SetLineWidth(0.5); 
            cb.SetLineDash(3, 2);
            cb.MoveTo(rect.Left, rect.Bottom - dashOffsetY);
            cb.LineTo(rect.Right, rect.Bottom - dashOffsetY);
            cb.Stroke();
            cb.RestoreState();

            PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, rect, "DefineButton-" + (++NumButtons));
            PdfFormField field = button.Field;
            field.Action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(localDestination, false);
            field.UserName = tooltip;
            writer.AddAnnotation(field);
        }
    }
```